# How to show the Connection Bar in a remote desktop session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

What is the keyboard shortcut to show the connection bar on an existing Remote Desktop session when the connection bar is hidden?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The Below Shortcut may work as stated in this [windows weblink.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/keyboard-shortcuts)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>: In full-screen mode, activate the connection bar

Comment: I think this is specific answer the OP was after :) Thanks

Comment: Also worth pointing out that when remoting onto a machine then remoting from that machine to another machine the connection bars overlap and it can be tricky to select the right one, in which case you can drag the 1st bar left/right to reveal the bar beneath.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer @Josh !

Comment: Perfect! Since my keyboard doesn't have a "break" button, I needed this to get out of the remote session

Comment: How do you pass CTRL-ALT-HOME when you're RDP'ing within an RDP?

Answer (score 63):

Since that interface requires a mouse to use anyway, I don't believe there is one. You just need to hover your mouse over the top edge to show it.

The knowledge base article "[List of the keyboard shortcuts that are available in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583)" has a section listing the special shortcuts used while in a Remote Desktop session.

Hovering at the top of the screen will only work is all you did was 'un-pin' the connection bar.  However, if prior to connecting you unchecked 'display the connection bar in full screen mode' on RDC's Display tab, then you need a different approach.  You cannot bring up the connection bar at all.  This may cause you to wonder how to get back to the local computer screen.  This is done via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> shortcut key combination which toggles the RDC window size on the local computer's desktop.

Comment: In Windows 8 and "display connection bar in full screen mode" is unchecked then <Ctrl> + <Alt> + <Home> shows the connection bar. You can then <Tab> through the minimize, maximize and close buttons on the bar.

Comment: On my multi-monitor remote desktop setup, hovering at the top middle of any screen fails to show the connection bar. <Ctrl> + <Alt> + <Home> works.