# Save Remote Desktop connection bar size and position

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-connection

Using RDC on Windows 10 connecting to a VM (also running Windows 10), I always have to manually change the size and position of the connection bar at the top of the window.

[image: RDC small]

But when I disconnect (or log off or restart the VM) and reconnect, the connection bar has reset.

[image]

How can the changes to RDC connection bar be "saved"?

Comment: Not sure how to natively do it, but could you use a program like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [Macro Express](https://www.macros.com/) to record a macro that does it, then use the RDC "Start the following program on connection" option to launch that macro when connection is established?

Comment: @Facebook Did you find a way?

Comment: @Facebook I didn't find a solution and the bounty is expired too. Did you get a chance to do any research? Thanks.

Comment: @Facebook No, I couldn't find anything. I did some extensive research on this before asking the question and mostly I found that Microsoft haven't provided this feature. Although, most of my attention has been on this [other question](https://superuser.com/q/1239157/274076) causing me more pain. However, I'll look into AutoIT. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good work around that can be used.

In the Remote Desktop Connection -> Display tab.
Uncheck "Display the connection bar when I use full screen".

Then you can either use either
ctrl alt home to show the connection bar.
or
ctrl alt break to change the rdp connection to windowed.

https://superuser.com/a/300124/359703