# RDC bar hides next RDC bar

Tags: remote-desktop

When connected with RDC to a server and then from that server connects to another or even several servers, the first RDC connection bar completely covers the next session connection bar. That makes it look as you are still working in the first RDC connected server. For some, maybe many, of us this is a frequent scenario that causes irritation to say the least, or even mistakes entering data into the "wrong" session.

How can RDC be made to show which endpoint is active, and not hide subsequent RDC session connection bars?

I can thing of several ways to resolve this chained session situation:

- Translucent connection bars. At least showing that what you see is not where your normal keystrokes ends up. This could be implemented regardless. (When Microsoft?)
- Last connection bar always on top. This too leaves no clue that this is a chained session but what you see is where your keystrokes lands.
- Configurable connection bar height, width and position, in the session configuration (and/or command line). With this option the first bar could be constantly moved (like slided) to an offset position, not hiding the next sessions.
- Remember last connection bar position. This is in part similar to [Save Remote Desktop connection bar size and position](https://superuser.com/questions/1240016/save-remote-desktop-connection-bar-size-and-position).

If any solutions already exists, please enlighten me.

P.S. I am not referring to or is interested in the hide connection bar option. That has its own pros and cons.

Comment: You seem to have 2 accounts. You might want to ask for a merger between this account and the other one https://superuser.com/users/927317/dum then edit in additional information

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, options to control the RDC top bar are limited.

A better approach would be to change the desktop background of the computers you access to show identifying information such as the computer name. Microsoft's [BGInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo) utility does just this:

> If you manage multiple computers you probably need BGInfo. It automatically displays relevant information about a Windows computer on the desktop's background, such as the computer name, IP address, service pack version, and more. You can edit any field as well as the font and background colors, and can place it in your startup folder so that it runs every boot, or even configure it to display as the background for the logon screen.

You can configure it to run on user logon or with Task Scheduler. This can be done using Group Policy so that it's automatically deployed to every system you might remotely access.

Comment: I have come to understand that RDC top bar is not ... optimal.
Your first suggestion assumes that I have control of endpoint settings. I dont'
But that information is not visible when an application is running i full screen mode on the endpoint. Only with clean desktop. Right? :(

Comment: @Dum Yes, you do need to see the Desktop. It's worth noting that if you don't have the option to run a lightweight utility such as BGInfo then your options in this scenario are *extremely* limited from and administration perspective.

Comment: So how can we have MS implement better "session within session" information? Or just allow us to save the connection bar position from session to session?

Comment: @Dum That would involve making a request to Microsoft. Doing that is outside this site's scope.

Comment: Right you are. I was a little too quick going for the ultimate solution. I have to find out how to make such a request, unless there is someone that knows a way ...

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to go into a server and from there go to another server, but its not always possible to circumvent this.

You can actually grab the blue bar and move it left or right, which will make it so that both bars are visible.

In addition, you can choose to not connect to the 2nd server full screen, but windowed. That way, anyone will know there is a 2nd server.

There is no other way. You need to train everyone to do this, it can't be forced.

Alternatively, you may want to consider to change the entrance to the first server. For example, if you use Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager, you can set it up so that it fills the entire screen, but not have that blue bar. If you then see the bar, you always know you are in a `server in a server` situation. Microsoft RDCM is free and a very good tool to manage many servers at once, but can just as easily be used to manage only a few servers.

Comment: Bad practice? I don’t know how relevant that is to the issue of seeing the true endpoint. For me it can't be circumvented.

I am looking for a sustainable RDC solution. Not activities and things to do (spend time on) in each RDC session. Shrinking and moving the connection bar every session is what I do now. 
From your suggestions I see no real improvement to me, and in basic you say it is not possible.
Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator if you want to limit the amount of open connections, you either use VPN or a gateway server. That is best practice.

Comment: No you don't. You don't need to use DMZ for that. All you need to do is VPN inside the network, so you can rdp based on local ip's from there. You only need to open the correct ports, depending on which protocol you use. We do it like this all the time.

Comment: Don't argue about connectivity best practices here. It is of topic.
Improved visibility of the endpoint connection bar is the information sought.

Comment: @dum, why not remove the first bar from the equation as my answer suggests?

Comment: Because then I dont know which WTS I am on.
And with sequential connects from WTS to WTS:s and then to a server, I am even more unaware of where input is destined. Remember I have no control over how each individual WTS or server is configured. I am a user. "All" ;) I want is for the connection bar from the last endpoint showing in full screen to be visible regardless of "earlier" connection bars.
It would be easier ;) if I was allowed to save the bar position and not only hide it. Other users seems to want to save too, but for other reasons. Maybe MS understands this one day.

Comment: And connnecting full screen is a requirement? I mean, if you go windowed, then its as obvious as it gets.