# How to hide Remote Desktop connection bar when run via Microsoft Remote Desktop (Windows 11)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

In Remote Desktop Connection app one can disable connection bar via:
https://superuser.com/a/300124/755248

However, I cannot find such option when using the Microsoft Remote Desktop application:
https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-remote-desktop/9WZDNCRFJ3PS

Any ideas how we can hide the connection bar for a remote desktop session started like this?

Note: I do not have access to the RDP files and access the remote machines by adding a subscription URL to the Microsoft Remote Desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different things :

The linked Super User answer refers to the desktop version of RDP,
while the second link refers to the Microsoft Store app.

These are two distinct and different apps with different options and
behavior.

In the desktop version of RDP you will find the connection bar option.

Comment: I am asking if the behavior described for Remote Desktop Connection application possible in the Remote Desktop application from Microsoft Store.

Comment: The Microsoft Store is rewritten in [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) and as new software has less options than the old classical version. It's probably using much less the registry and there is very little information about its options. UWP is basically a failure and Microsoft no longer develops it. If you need this option, you should use the classical version.